# Multiple instances of a jquery slider on one page

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, carousel

I wrote a pretty simple slider using jQuery. It works by counting and numbering the child img elements and displaying the img that corresponds with a counter variable that increases as a user presses the "right" button and decreases if the "left" button is pressed. It works fine unless there are multiple instances of it on a page.(I think because the variables are global)

One button ends up controlling the flow of all of the sliders. Additionally, only one slider will show an image at a time because they all refer back to the same variables.

**Is there a way to make each instance of the slider have its own counter ($n) and slide number ($slides) variables?**

Here's a jfiddle with what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/Mn4jk/2/ (although no actual images)

And here is the direct html and jQuery

html:

```
<div>
<img src="../graphics/arrow_left.png" class="left" alt="left">
<img src="../graphics/arrow_right.png" class="right" alt="right">
<div class="carousel">
    <img src="../graphics/img1.png" alt="1">
    <img src="../graphics/img2.png" alt="2">
    <img src="../graphics/img3.png" alt="3">
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).ready(function () {

var $n = 0;
var $slides = $('.carousel img').length - 1;

$('.right').click(function () {
    if ($n <= ($slides - 1)) {
        $('.carousel img').eq($n).fadeOut('400');
        $n++;
        $('.carousel img').eq($n).delay('400').fadeIn('400');
    } else {
        $('.carousel img').eq($slides).fadeOut('400');
        $n = 0;
        $('.carousel img').eq(0).delay('400').fadeIn('400');
    }
});

$('.left').click(function () {
    if ($n >= 1) {
        $('.carousel img').eq($n).fadeOut('400');
        $n--;
        $('.carousel img').delay('400').eq($n).fadeIn('400');
    } else {
        $('.carousel img').eq(0).fadeOut('400');
        $n = ($slides)
    }
    $('.carousel img').delay('400').eq($n).fadeIn('400');
});

$('.carousel img').eq($n).fadeIn('400');
});
```

I know I could just copy the code and make a new class, but I'd rather a solution that would allow for any number of sliders to be used on one page.

Comment: You could try using data-attributes="count" and manage it through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Javascript has "classes" which allow this functionality. Classes can be instantiated multiple times and each instance has it's own set of variables, methods, etc. Classes are the key building blocks to "object orientated programming" (OOP).

For more information search for "Javascript classes" on google.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Note: There are multiple ways to define a Javascript class. So the tutorials out there will show different methods.

---

I do admire the willingness and desire to build your own. However, there are plenty of libraries out there with this functionality (just search for Javascript gallery).

Example JSFiddle as a class: http://jsfiddle.net/Mn4jk/4/

```
var Slider = function(element) {
    this.$n = 0;
    this.img = element.find(".carousel img");
    this.$slide = this.img.length-1;
    this.left = element.find(".left");
    this.right = element.find(".right");

    this.buttons();

    this.img.eq(this.$n).fadeIn('400');
}

Slider.prototype.buttons = function() {
    var that = this;

    this.right.click(function () {
        if (that.$n <= (that.$slide - 1)) {
            that.img.eq(that.$n).fadeOut('400');
            that.$n++;
            that.img.eq(that.$n).delay('400').fadeIn('400');
        } else {
            that.img.eq(that.$slide).fadeOut('400');
            that.$n = 0;
            that.img.eq(0).delay('400').fadeIn('400');
        }
    });

    this.left.click(function () {
        if (that.$n >= 1) {
            that.img.eq(that.$n).fadeOut('400');
            that.$n--;
            that.img.delay('400').eq(that.$n).fadeIn('400');
        } else {
            that.img.eq(0).fadeOut('400');
            that.$n = (that.$slide);
        }
        that.img.delay('400').eq(that.$n).fadeIn('400');
    });
};




$(window).ready(function () {
    var slider1 = new Slider(jQuery("#slider-instance"));    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll look into classes and update if/when I solve it

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm still pretty new to js/jQuery and wanted to build one for myself so that I could test myself and really understand what was happening. Using "this" and "that" has proven to be final hurdle, but this will definitely help.

Comment: "this" and "that" is just to circumvent scope issues. "this" within the click event handlers would reference the element clicked, NOT the class a whole. I create a variable "that" in the button method which does refer to the class; it could be named anything "self", "myClass", "whatever"...but, that is semi-accepted variable name for it.

Comment: thanks again, updated the fiddle to include two instances if anyone is curious.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mn4jk/5/